# How to use \affiliation in RevTex revtex4-2 Template in order to have the authors in the same line?

Tags: revtex, affiliation

2 template (with two columns) and I would like to have the author of the paper in the same row and the affiliations all together below the authors.
I'm using the following code:

```
\documentclass[reprint,amsmath,amssymb,aps,]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{C:..}}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}  

\begin{document}    
\title{Title}  

\author{Author1}    
\affiliation{Affiliation1}    
\author{Author2}    
\affiliation{Affiliation2}

\collaboration{Z}    
\date{\today} 

\begin{abstract}    
Article abstract     
\end{abstract} 

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

In this way I obtain the first author and below it the affiliation, even more below it the second author and below the second author its affiliation. Like this:

[image: what i obtain]

How can I have the authors in the same row and below the the affiliations like this?

[image: what I want to obtain]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried to list first all `\author` statements and then all `\affiliation` statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First list all `\author`s, then all `\affiliation`s. By default, multiple authors/affiliations are separated by `and`, but this can be changed to `,` using

```
\def\andname{\unskip,}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[reprint,amsmath,amssymb,aps,]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{C:..}}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}  
\def\andname{\unskip,}
\begin{document}    
\title{Title}  

\author{Author1}    
\author{Author2}    
\affiliation{Affiliation1}    
\affiliation{Affiliation2}

\collaboration{Z}    
\date{\today} 

\begin{abstract}    
Article abstract     
\end{abstract} 

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think *superscriptaddress* option in the documentclass is the official way to achieve the same result.

reference: [Revtex 4-2 Switching order of alt-affiliations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638055/revtex-4-2-switching-order-of-alt-affiliations)