# Revtex 4-2 Switching order of alt-affiliations

Tags: revtex, affiliation

So I am using this template here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/revtex-4-dot-2-template-and-sample/yydsrzvrqrzs
Using this code in the author part,

```
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
superscriptaddress,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps
]{revtex4-2}

\begin{document}
\preprint{APS/123-QED}

\title{Title}% Force line breaks with \\
%\thanks{A footnote to the article title}%

\author{Author 1}
\altaffiliation[Also at ]{Physics Department, XYZ University.}
\affiliation{Affil 1}%
\author{Author 2}
\altaffiliation[Also at ]{Physics Department, XYZ University.}
\affiliation{Affil 1}%
\author{Author 3} 
\affiliation{Affil 2}%
\affiliation{Affil 3}%
\author{Author 4} 
\email{email@com}
\affiliation{Affil 4}%
```

the alt-affiliation and email will appear the following:

[image: Top of page 1]

[image: At the end of page 1]

(I cut the irrelevant part of the page)
However, I want the email to be mentioned first with the "*" symbol instead of the alt-affiliation. How do I change the symbol and the order of these?

Comment: Do you want to maintain the altaffiliation of other authors? If so, with what symbol?

Comment: Yes, I do want to maintain them. What I want is to keep everything as shown above, just swap the text "email@com" with "Also at Physics Department XYZ University.".